# Delete files from the folder older than 4 days

Tags: c#, datetime, file-io, delete-file

I would like to run a timer for every 5 hours and delete the files from the folder older than 4 days. Could you please with sample code?

Comment: Is there a specific part of this you need help with? Nobody is going to simply write the code for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it hasn't been mentioned, I would recommend using a `System.Threading.Timer` for something like this. Here's an example implementation:

```
System.Threading.Timer DeleteFileTimer = null;

private void CreateStartTimer()
{
    TimeSpan InitialInterval = new TimeSpan(0,0,5);
    TimeSpan RegularInterval = new TimeSpan(5,0,0);

    DeleteFileTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(QueryDeleteFiles, null, 
            InitialInterval, RegularInterval);

}

private void QueryDeleteFiles(object state)
{
    //Delete Files Here... (Fires Every Five Hours).
    //Warning: Don't update any UI elements from here without Invoke()ing
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Deleting Files...");
}

private void StopDestroyTimer()
{
    DeleteFileTimer.Change(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite,
    System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);

    DeleteFileTimer.Dispose();
}
```

This way, you can run your file deletion code in a windows service with minimal hassle.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. When do I have to use the StopDestroyTimer()?

Comment: Simply call when you want the timer to stop or when your service/application is shutting down. The most important thing is calling it sometime - (System.Threading.)Timer implements IDisposable so the call to Dispose() is needed.

Answer (score 8):

```
DateTime CutOffDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-4)
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
FileInfo[] fi = di.GetFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < fi.Length; i++)
{
    if (fi[i].LastWriteTime < CutOffDate)
    {
        File.Delete(fi[i].FullName);
    }
}
```

You can substitute `LastWriteTime` property for something else, that's just what I use when clearing out an Image Cache in an app I have.

**EDIT:**

Though this doesnt include the timer part... I'll let you figure that part out yourself.  A little Googling should show you several ways to do it on a schedule.

Answer (score 0):

```
string nlogfolderpath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/LogInfo");
string[] nfiles = Directory.GetFiles(nlogfolderpath);
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(nlogfolderpath);

foreach (string file in nfiles)
{
      FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
      if (fi.LastAccessTime < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3))
      {
          fi.Delete();
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**