# Clear File Contents After X Amount Of Time

Tags: c#, twitch

I need a way of clearing a text file after a certain period of time. This is what I have so far

```
List<string> previousWeaponList = new StreamWriter("PreviousList.txt");
```

So this is reading the previous weapon list into the file after a weapon is requested the weapon is written to that list. Once I do this I have a file which will get full very quickly if I save every single request, which is why I need to clean it out every X amount of time.

Would it be possible to do it like this?

```
private Thread fileCleaner;
public void FileCleaner()
{
    fileCleaner = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.Run))
}
```

Then just have a run function which if it's true it will just write to the file and then use a

```
Thread.Sleep();
```

I heard using Threads for time isn't a good idea, but I am not an expert on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very similar question and answer here:

[Delete files from the folder older than 4 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374094/delete-files-from-the-folder-older-than-4-days)

Relevant answer:

> I would recommend using a System.Threading.Timer for something like this. Here's an example implementation:
>
> ```
> System.Threading.Timer DeleteFileTimer = null;
>
> private void CreateStartTimer()
> {
>  TimeSpan InitialInterval = new TimeSpan(0,0,5);
>  TimeSpan RegularInterval = new TimeSpan(5,0,0);
>
>  DeleteFileTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(QueryDeleteFiles, null, 
>         InitialInterval, RegularInterval);
>
> }
>
> private void QueryDeleteFiles(object state)
> {
>   //Delete Files Here... (Fires Every Five Hours).
>   //Warning: Don't update any UI elements from here without Invoke()ing
>   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Deleting Files...");
> }
>
> private void StopDestroyTimer()
> {
>   DeleteFileTimer.Change(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite,
>   System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
>
>   DeleteFileTimer.Dispose();
> }
> ```
>
> This way, you can run your file deletion code in a windows service with minimal hassle.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and set its `Elapsed` event's callback to the file cleaning method.

```
var timer = new Timer(10000);
timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => File.Delete("C:\\your_file.txt");
timer.Enabled = true;
```

If you ever need to stop the timer, set `timer.Enabled` to `false`.